# Cassandra 3.9 stuck in joining state

Tags: cassandra

I have a 14 node cassandra 3.9 cluster with ~250GB of data on each node. Recently I have been attempting to add a 15th node to this cluster. The node is stuck in Joining state for the past 2 days. netstas is clear. The main thing I find suspicious in the system.log for that joining node is errors like these.

```
ERROR [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2018-02-16 15:43:32,635 Message.java:617 - Unexpected exception during request; channel = [id: 0x8ed1cb3b, L:/**.**.**.42:9042 - R:/**.**.**.**:41614]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator.authenticate(PasswordAuthenticator.java:88) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator.access$300(PasswordAuthenticator.java:59) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator$PlainTextSaslAuthenticator.getAuthenticatedUser(PasswordAuthenticator.java:220) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.messages.AuthResponse.execute(AuthResponse.java:78) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Message.java:513) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Message.java:407) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) [netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar:4.0.39.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366) [netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar:4.0.39.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$600(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:35) [netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar:4.0.39.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$7.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar:4.0.39.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:164) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:109) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
```

This error message is from a client trying to connect to this node. It seems to fail authentication. How might I proceed in this situation? How should I bring this node to normalcy?

Comment: On the stuck node, check `nodetool netstats`.  It sounds so me like one of the streams failed.  If things in netstats don't appear to be progressing, stop the node, wipe it, and rejoin it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different problems here,

1. The auth issue that client is facing is related to a bug with Cassandra 3.9 during bootstrap of new nodes. It has been resolved in the later versions of Cassandra as documented here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12813.
2. We had a streaming issue similar to this with Cassandra 3.9. While taking a deeper look at the system.log there was an error with huge partition (partition greater than 100MB) not able to compacted since it exceeds the default commitlog_segment_size. . We were able to get around it once we increased the commitlog_segment_size_in_mb to 512mb. Check for huge partition warnings and adjust the size accordingly.

Comment: Thank you once again for the very useful input. Yes the JIRA ticket you linked above seems exactly my case. I will look to upgrade.